# Change field depending on if field value is contained in other table

Tags: abap

So my goal is to change a field in a table for those entries that the value is contained in some other table.
So for example.

If the name "John" from table_abc is contained in the table l_t_xyz then change the value to "ABC".

My approach to this:

`SELECT * FROM table_xyz INTO TABLE @DATA(l_t_xyz).`

Let's say one of the field of table_xyz is NAME.

And i have a second table, also with the field NAME where I want to change one of the fields

```
LOOP AT table_abc ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<abc_line>) WHERE name in table_xyz-name.
   <abc_line>-name = 'ABC'
ENDLOOP.
```

But this gives me an error that table_xyz is a table without a header line, therefore has no component called "NAME".

How do I solve this. Also I can't find any documentation on the keyword IN. Maybe I am using it wrong in this case.

Comment: For `LOOP AT ... WHERE ... IN ...` here is the path in the ABAP documentation: `ABAP Index` > `IN` > `Relational Expression`

Comment: why not to use FOR ALL ENTRIES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found another solution, which was inspired by Eray answer.
Basing on ranges

```
SELECT 'I' AS sign,
       'EQ' AS option,
        name as low
        name as high
        into table @DATA(range_table)

LOOP AT table_abc[] ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<abc_line>) WHERE name in range_table.
<abc_line>-name = 'abc'
ENDLOOP.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define a range for name values which stored in table_xyz.

That's quick example:

```
TYPES lr_name_range_type TYPE RANGE OF name. "you should define appropriate data type

DATA : lr_name_range TYPE lr_name_range_type.


//define macro
    DEFINE fill_range.
      lr_name_range = VALUE #( BASE lr_name_range( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' low = &1 ) ).
    END-OF-DEFINITION.

//fill range according to table_xyz values
LOOP AT table_xyz ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_xyz>).
  fill_range <fs_xyz>-name.
ENDLOOP.

//Now you can use IN keyword for your loop
LOOP AT table_abc ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<abc_line>) WHERE name in lr_name_range.
   <abc_line>-name = 'ABC'
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I am testing it and was wondering what do you mean with 
make_range <fs_xyz>-name.

Comment: Because i have found something like fill_range: <fs_xyz>-name, but it does not work. I get an error, "method fill_range" is uknown or PROTECTED or PRIVATE", so it assumes it is a Method :/

Comment: Hey sorry,  I edited response. It's should be fill_range instead of make_range.

Answer (score 0):

It's faster:

```
data lt_name type hashed table of table_xyz-name with unique default key.

SELECT * FROM table_xyz INTO TABLE @DATA(l_t_xyz).

lt_name = value #( for group fgv_name of <fs_xyz> in l_t_xyz 
 group by <fs_xyz>-name
 ( fgv_name ) 
).

LOOP AT table_abc ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_line>).
  if line_exists( lt_name[ table_line = <fs_line>-name ] )
   <fs_line>-name = 'ABC'.
  endif.
ENDLOOP.
```